# Uploading more than 100mb using the SkyDrive API

Tags: c++, onedrive

My apologies if this has been asked before.  I've searched, but I can't seem to find the answer.

The SkyDrive API has a file upload limit of 100mb.  There are apps out there that bypass this upload limit, for example, PDF Expert (iOS).  Do you guys know of any way to get around this issue?